# Pandas delete all rows which contains "required value" in all column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
 A     B    C    D
BUY   150   Q   2018
SELL  63    Q   2018
N      N    N    N

V      v    v    v
SELL  53    Q   2018
```

I want to delete all rows which contains all column a V or N

Output data frame will be :-

```
    A     B     C    D
   BUY   150    Q   2018
   SELL  63     Q   2018

   SELL  53     Q   2018
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df.isin(['V', 'v', 'N', 'n']).all(axis=1)]
print (df)
      A    B  C     D
0   BUY  150  Q  2018
1  SELL   63  Q  2018
4  SELL   53  Q  2018
```

**Detail**:

First compare by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
print (df.isin(['V', 'v', 'N', 'n']))
       A      B      C      D
0  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False
2   True   True   True   True
3   True   True   True   True
4  False  False  False  False
```

Get rows if [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) `True`s per rows:

```
print (df.isin(['V', 'v', 'N', 'n']).all(axis=1))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

Invert condition by `~`:

```
print (~df.isin(['V', 'v', 'N', 'n']).all(axis=1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `pd.DataFrame.apply` with `set` to create a Boolean mask:

```
res = df[~(df.apply(set, axis=1) <= set('NnVv'))]

print(res)

      A    B  C     D
0   BUY  150  Q  2018
1  SELL   63  Q  2018
4  SELL   53  Q  2018
```

Note `<=` is syntactic sugar for [`set.issubset`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=issubset#frozenset.issubset).

This scales well for a large number of columns. Use @jezrael's `pd.DataFrame.all` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50717966/9209546) for a large number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

`replace` + `dropna`(Notice `thresh` is the key here)

```
df.replace(dict(zip(list('NnVv'),[np.nan]*4))).dropna(thresh=1)
Out[513]: 
      A    B  C     D
0   BUY  150  Q  2018
1  SELL   63  Q  2018
4  SELL   53  Q  2018
```